# How to merge a grouped and aggregated df?

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have grouped and aggregated transactions per account number (to calculate monthly statisitics) and now I want to merge the output with another dataframe on account numbers. The account numbers are however no longer in the index/columns.

## Group transactions per account and month and perform aggregated calculations

```
df1 = df.groupby(['AcctNr','Month']).sum().groupby(level=0).agg({'Amount': 'mean', 'median', max, 'std', percentile(75), iqr]})


df1.columns = ["_".join(x) for x in df1.columns.ravel()]
```

This results in the following results from

```
df1.columns:



Index(['Amount_mean', 'Amount_median', 'Amount_max', 'Amount_std',
       'Amount_percentile_75', 'Amount_iqr', 'UpperBP'],
      dtype='object')
```

When I try to merge with another DF on AcctNr i get:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='AcctNr')



KeyError: 'AcctNr'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep account number in your df1 because without it you can not join.

If you don't need it in your final df you can drop it with

```
df3 = df3.drop("AcctNr", axis=1)
```